# Wix API - How to get Access token for using rest API for my app

Tags: api, velo

I following this document: https://dev.wix.com/api/rest/getting-started/authentication for create api with my app (on Wix), on `Step 4 - App Submits the Authorization Code`: I got `APP_ID` and `APP_SECRET` but what is `AUTH_CODE`? How to do get it?

And, what I should enter the Redirect URL when create app:
[What should enter the Redirect URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUXRo.png)

Regrads

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the wix api rest, you need to have a server running that will be called once the user install your app in his site.

When that occurs, wix calls to your server and sends the auth code and the instance id. Thats is explained on the step 3 of the documentation.

Only when the user approves the required permissions of your app, is when you can request the access token to access the user site data.

On your app **Redirect URL** is the endpoint on your server where you receive the auth token and the instance id that identify the user page that approves access.
On the other side, **App URL** is used by wix when the user install your app from the market, so you will need also an endpoint for save some extra data there too. (a *token* on step 1)